# Как завершить работу приложения

Tags: xamarin

Доброго дня. 
Пытаюсь потихоньку осваивать кросс-платформенную разработку с помощью Xamarin, и в своих потугах добрался до этапа, когда при определенных ошибках приложение должно само завершить свою работу. И с удивлением обнаружил, что мануалов по правильному завершению работы нет. Возможно конечно, я их просто не нашел, но что делать дальше все равно непонятно. Нигде даже не указанно, является ли эта процедура платформенно-зависимой или реализуется общей логикой. В общем, если кто знает, как это делать, или поделиться ссылкой, буду очень благодарен.

Answer (score 1):

Закрытие приложения зависит от конкретной платформы. То есть реализация закрытия приложения у каждой платформы свое.

Android: `Process.KillProcess(Process.MyPid());`

IOS: `Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();`

Windows: `Application.Current.Exit();`

Answer (score 1):

для Андроида

```
public class MainActivity 

MainPage.closeAction += qwe;

void qwe()
    {
        FinishAndRemoveTask();
    }
```

в

```
MainPage
static public Action closeAction;

private void BtnExit_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {         
        Process.KillProcess(Process.MyPid());
        closeAction.Invoke();
    }
```

Comment: добавил Process.KillProcess(Process.MyPid()); так как приложение убивается, а процесс и объекты остаются висеть